# Escaping wildcards in VStudio launch configuration broken?

Tags: visual-studio-code, escaping, vscode-debugger

I want to test the wildcard treatment of my Python script. Therefore I want to handover a file path which contains wildcards e.g. *data/*.xml*.

If I call my script directly in the shell

```
my_script.py data/\*.xml
```

The escape of the wildcard works fine and the wildcard is seen by my script.

However, I'm not able to achieve this with my launch configuration of vscode.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: my_script",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/my_script.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": ["mine", "${workspaceFolder}/data/\\*.xml"]
        }
    ]
}
```

This launch fails:

```
%  cd /Users/tom/Documents/evaluate ; env /Users/tom/Library/python3.8/bin/python /Users/tom/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.8.103604/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 52992 -- /Users/tom/Documents/evaluate/my_script.py mine /Users/tom/Documents/evaluate/data/\\*.xml 

zsh: no matches found: /Users/tom/Documents/evaluate/data/\*.xml
```

I tried several other variants to quote the wildcard without success e.g. the shell escape didn't work and the shell expanded the wildcard before the path is handed over to the script.

Any idea how I have to define the path properly in the "args:" of my launch configuration?

Answer (score 0):

It really seems to be a bug. The escaping does not work as expected and differs depending on the used console.

Please refer the discussion in the related [Github ticket.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/91578)